# How to set MongoDB on a linux based server

Tags: linux, mongodb, server

I need to set up MongoDB database on my linux server. What are steps I should follow for this? And how can I access this database from outside the server? Using some GUI for mongodb by providing the DB url?

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/install-mongodb-on-rhel-centos-fedora-ubuntu-debian/

Comment: Please go through above link once.